# Python Tornado KeyError When removing client from clients set

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, keyerror

I have a Python Tornado Websocket server that stores clients in a shared set() so that I know how many clients are connected.

The challenge is that calling `on_close` after `WebSocketClosedError` raises a `KeyError` and the client-instance is not removed from the set of connected clients. This error has caused my server to accumulate over 1000 clients even when the active clients are only around 5.

My Code:

```
import tornado.iostream
import tornado.websocket
import asyncio


class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    socket_active_message = {"status": "Socket Connection Active"}
    waiters = set()

    def initialize(self):
        self.client_name = "newly_connected"

    def open(self):
        print('connection opened')
        # https://kite.com/python/docs/tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.set_nodelay
        self.set_nodelay(True)
        SocketHandler.waiters.add(self)

    def on_close(self):
        print("CLOSED!", self.client_name)
        SocketHandler.waiters.remove(self)

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        # Override the origin check if needed
        return True

    async def send_updates(self, message):
        print('starting socket service loop')
        loop_counter = 0
        while True:
            try:
                await self.write_message({'status': 82317581})
            except tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError:
                self.on_close()
            except tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError:
                self.on_close()
            except Exception as e:
                self.on_close()
                print('Exception e:', self.client_name)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.05)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print("RECEIVED :", message)
        self.client_name = message
        await self.send_updates(message)


def run_server():
    # Create tornado application and supply URL routes
    webApp = tornado.web.Application(
        [
            (
                r"/",
                SocketHandler,
                {},
            ),
        ]
    )

    application = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(webApp)
    webApp.listen(3433)
    # Start IO/Event loop
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


run_server()
```

The Stack-trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/EE/projects/new/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/mnt/c/Users/EE/projects/new/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 278, in get
    await self.ws_connection.accept_connection(self)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/EE/projects/new/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 881, in accept_connection
    await self._accept_connection(handler)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/EE/projects/new/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 964, in _accept_connection
    await self._receive_frame_loop()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/EE/projects/new/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1118, in _receive_frame_loop
    await self._receive_frame()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/EE/projects/new/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1209, in _receive_frame
    await handled_future
  File "/mnt/c/Users/EE/projects/new/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/EE/projects/new/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 658, in <lambda>
    self.stream.io_loop.add_future(result, lambda f: f.result())
  File "ask_So.py", line 50, in on_message
    await self.send_updates(message)
  File "ask_So.py", line 39, in send_updates
    self.on_close()
  File "ask_So.py", line 26, in on_close
    SocketHandler.waiters.remove(self)
KeyError: <__main__.SocketHandler object at 0x7ffef9f25520>
```

I have tried moving the waiters set outside the class but it still produces the same behaviour.

To simulate `WebSocketClosedError`: open many browser tabs as clients and close one browser tab at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `self.on_close()` is being called twice. Once you're calling it manually from inside `send_updates()` and then later, when a connection is actually closed, Tornado is also calling `self.on_close()`. Since the `self` object was already removed from the set the first time, it raises a `KeyError` the second time.

If you want to close the connection, just call [`self.close()`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.close). The `self.on_close()` method will be called by Tornado automatically.

Also, you can handle the exception in a `try...except` block inside `on_close`.

---

### Update

The previous part of this answer should fix the `KeyError` related problem. This update is regarding why the clients are not being removed from `waiters` set.

So, I tested your code and found a major problem with it here:

```
 async def on_message(self, message):
    print("RECEIVED :", message)
    self.client_name = message
    await self.send_updates(message) # <- This is problematic
```

Whenever a client sends a message, it will run `self.send_updates` method. So even if there's only one client that sends a message, let's say, 10 times, `send_updates` will also be called 10 times and, as a result, **you will have 10 `while` loops running simultaneously!**

As the number of loops increase, it ultimately blocks the server. That means Tornado has no time to run other code as it's busy juggling so many `while` loops. Hence, the clients from the `waiters` are never removed.

**Solution**

Instead of calling `send_updates` everytime a message arrives, you can call it just one time. Just have a single `while` loop to send updates to all clients.

I'd update the code like this:

```
class SocketHandler(...):
    # Make it a classmethod so that it can be 
    # called without an instance
    @classmethod
    async def send_updates(cls):
        print('starting socket service loop')
        loop_counter = 0
        while True:
            for waiter in cls.waiters:
                # use `waiter` instead of `self`
                try:
                    await waiter.write_message({'status': 82317581})
                    ...

            await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
```

Instead of calling `send_updates` from `on_message`, you'll have to tel IOLoop to call it once:

```
def run_server():
    ... 

    # schedule SocketHandler.send_updates to be run
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(SocketHandler.send_updates)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

This will have only one `while` loop running for all clients.

Comment: Thanks @xyres, 
The challenge is that the number of connected clients does not reduce even after this. The len of `SocketHandler.waiters` remains the same. 
For Example, even after closing all browser client-tabs, the set of connected clients remains full.

Comment: This means, even though I'm trying to remove the client twice, the client is not removed from the set at all.

Comment: @simic0de I've updated the answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks @xyres This is such a wonderful development, especially in the IOLoop. I’m going to try it and provide feedback.